# How to eliminate delimiter during concatenation if a column is NULL/Has no Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am concatenation two fields in my query:

```
SELECT LASTNAME + ', ' + FIRSTNAME AS NAME FROM MyTable;
```

JULIA ROBERTS = ROBERTS, JULIA
NULL   DONALD = NULL

In few rows, the firstname is missing, and my code concatenates with NULL to return NULL value for NAME.

If I use below query, it returns me comma along with the result which is not needed.

```
SELECT LASTNAME + ',' + ISNULL(FIRSTNAME) AS NAME FROM MyTable;
```

JULIA ROBERTS = ROBERTS, JULIA
NULL   DONALD = DONALD,

Is there a way I can eliminate comma if firstname is NULL in DB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT LASTNAME + case when FIRSTNAME is null
                       then ''
                       else ',' + FIRSTNAME
                  end AS NAME
 FROM MyTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LASTNAME + ISNULL(',' + FIRSTNAME, '') AS NAME FROM MyTable;
```